# Importing code as a module runs much slower than a single block of code in Python

Tags: image, sockets, python-3.5, raspberry-pi3

I'm writing a code to stream images form raspberry-pi3 to my laptop.
I wrote two versions of code, one using module and other as single block of code. 
I'm putting the code here (more details follow the code)

Code that runs fast:

```py
import picamera
import socket
import struct
import time
import io

stream_client= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
stream_client.connect(('192.168.43.34',9000))
print('connected')
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution=(320,240)
camera.color_effects=(128,128)
camera.framerate=18
time.sleep(2)
stream = io.BytesIO()
count=0
start=time.time()

try:
    for i in camera.capture_continuous(stream,'jpeg',use_video_port=True):
        count+=1
        stream_client.sendall(struct.pack('<L',stream.tell()))
        stream_client.sendall(struct.pack('<h',count))
        stream_client.sendall(stream.getvalue())
        stream.seek(0)
        stream.truncate()
        if(time.time()-start>10):
            break
finally:
    stream_client.sendall(struct.pack('<L',0))
    stream_client.close()
    camera.close()
    print('connection closed')
```

The codes that runs slowly:

Module (contained in a different file "CameraStreamModule.py" in same folder):

```py
'''
MODULE NAME: CAMERA STREAMING MODULE
OBJECTIVE: TO SEND IMAGE DATA FROM RASPBERRY-PI3 TO LAPTOP VIA TCP/IP STREAM
HARDWARE USED: RASPBERRY PI 3, PI CAMERA REV 1.3
PYTHON VERSION: 3.5.3
DATE WRITTEN: 8-1-2018
'''

'''************************************************************** IMPORTING MODULES ***********************************************************************'''
import picamera # PI CAMERA MODULE
import socket # MODULE TO HANDLE TCP/IP CONNECTION AND TRANSFER 
import struct # MODULE TO CONVERT DATA TO BYTE-LIKE OBJECTS (REQUIRED BY SOCKET METHODS)
import time # MODULE FOR TIME RELATED FUNCTIONS
import io # MODULE USED TO CREATE IN-MEMORY DATA STREAMS
'''************************************************************ MODULE IMPORTS END HERE *******************************************************************'''

'''*********************************************************** DECLARING GLOBAL VARIABLES *****************************************************************'''
LIMITED_STREAM = False # Stream only for short time when true
LIMIT_TIME= 10 # Seconds
stream = io.BytesIO()
stream_client= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
count=0
'''*********************************************************** GLOBAL VARIABLES END HERE ******************************************************************'''

'''************************************************************** METHOD DEFINITIONS ***********************************************************************'''


def Client_init (Server_ip,Server_port): # (str,int) expected as parameter
    global stream_client,start,LIMITED_STREAM
    stream_client.connect((Server_ip,Server_port))
    if LIMITED_STREAM :
        start=time.time()
    print('connected')


def Camera_init (Resolution_tuple,Colour_tuple,Frame_rate): # (int_tuple,int_tuple,int) expected as parameter
    global camera
    camera.resolution= Resolution_tuple
    camera.color_effects=Colour_tuple
    camera.framerate= Frame_rate
    time.sleep(2)


'''
THIS METHOD IS INTENDED TO BE CALLED INSIDE "for i in camera.capture_continuous(stream,'jpeg',use_video_port=True):" CONTINUOUSLY. ALSO .close() FOR SOCKET
AND CAMERA MUST BE CALLED SEPERATELY.
'''
def Send_frame (): 
    global count,stream_client,stream,LIMITED_STREAM

    count+=1
    stream_client.sendall(struct.pack('<L',stream.tell()))
    stream_client.sendall(struct.pack('<h',count))
    stream_client.sendall(stream.getvalue())
    stream.seek(0)
    stream.truncate()
    if LIMITED_STREAM:
        if(time.time()-start>LIMIT_TIME):
            raise Exception('Time Finished')

'''********************************************************* METHOD DEFINITIONS END HERE ******************************************************************'''
```

The calling code:

```py
import importlib

Camera_module= importlib.import_module('CameraStreamModule')

Camera_module.LIMITED_STREAM= True
Camera_module.Client_init('192.168.1.102',9000)
Camera_module.Camera_init((320,240),(128,128),18)
try:
    for i in Camera_module.camera.capture_continuous(Camera_module.stream,'jpeg',use_video_port=True):
        Camera_module.Send_frame()
finally:
    Camera_module.camera.close()
    Camera_module.stream_client.sendall(struct.pack('<L',0))
    Camera_module.stream_client.close()
    print('connection closed')
```

The first code streams about 179 images in 10 seconds and the second version does about 133 images which is a drastic reduction. I just wanted to create a module to make code more manageable and readable.

I have started coding in Python quite recently and I know that my method of coding may look ridiculous to more experienced coders (trust me, I'm trying to improve). Can anyone tell me what could be the reason of this slowdown?

I have observed that even changing the WiFi connection has an effect on the amount of data transferred in a given amount of time, so I have kept the WiFi connection the same for both versions of code.

I think that this slowdown occurrs because I'm passing a lot of data back and forth between modules ?

In any case, any advice/help regarding the code is welcome.

P.S: If you feel that my way of asking questions on this platform is not up to the mark and I need to give more or reduce the details, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found out the problem. Actually in the reciever code that I created , I had written a lot of print() statements for debugging purpose. which were causing the delay and due to this I was loosing some data since the socket transmission was asynchronous (and i did not handle the problem of data loss in the code). Along with this and probably the delay in passing large array data, back and forth between the modules caused this problem

Leaving this answer here just in case someone finds it useful.